Can I fine tune a Gemini 1.5 Flash model without using Vertex?
I'm building a technical support chatbot and want to leverage a pre-trained Large Language Model (LLM) for human language understanding. I would like to use Gemini 1.5 Flash API for this, but I don't want to use Vertex API as it consideraly rises the costs. So my question is: can I train a Gemini 1.5 Flash model, so it understands my business and creates responses based on it, without adquiring Vertex Credentials?

Yes you can tune AI studio gemini tuning
The model will then be stored in your account, your not charged for it last i remember
import time

base_model = "models/gemini-1.5-flash-001-tuning"
training_data = [
    {"text_input": "1", "output": "2"},
    # ... more examples ...
    # ...
    {"text_input": "seven", "output": "eight"},
]
operation = genai.create_tuned_model(
    # You can use a tuned model here too. Set `source_model="tunedModels/..."`
    display_name="increment",
    source_model=base_model,
    epoch_count=20,
    batch_size=4,
    learning_rate=0.001,
    training_data=training_data,
)

for status in operation.wait_bar():
    time.sleep(10)

result = operation.result()
print(result)
# # You can plot the loss curve with:
# snapshots = pd.DataFrame(result.tuning_task.snapshots)
# sns.lineplot(data=snapshots, x='epoch', y='mean_loss')

model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name=result.name)
result = model.generate_content("III")
print(result.text)  # IV

Just remember unless you use the paid version of gemini then the data you send it is not private.  It could be used to train other models.
